The italic version of the "Raleway-Medium" font
While I am trying the raleway font, I am looking for the italic version of Raleway-Medium font.
This command (a MWE) give me the Raleway-Medium font, how do I make it italic?
{\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont some texts}
}

Directly using \textit{some texts} would not work. I guess the package needs to be loaded properly? Any advice?

Avoid using \fontspec in a document.

\newfontfamily{\ralewaymeditalic}{Raleway-Medium-Italic.otf} then {\ralewaymeditalic <text>}

@mbert, worked thank you!

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please note, a code snippet is not a MWE. Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

The Raleway font family provides 9 separate font weights: Thin, ExtraLight, Light, Regular, Medium, SemiBold, Bold, ExtraBold, and Black.
I take it that you have decided to use the Medium weight as the default or base weight. You may wish to not only define an associated Italic font shape but also the associated Bold and Bold-Italic font weights/shapes. A handy rule of thumb is to choose a bold weight that's 2 or more levels "heavier" than the chosen base weight. In the case of the Raleway fonts, that would be the "Bold" weight. Hence, give something like the following a try.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Raleway}[% "Bold" is 2 steps heavier than "Medium"
    UprightFont    = * Medium,
    ItalicFont     = * Medium Italic,
    BoldFont       = * Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = * Bold Italic]
\newcommand\HW{Hello World.} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\HW\ \textit{\HW} \textbf{\HW} \textit{\textbf{\HW}}
\end{document}


Try this on for size.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{raleway}[ItalicFont=Raleway-Regular-Italic.otf]


\begin{document}
    Content
    \emph{Italic}
\end{document}


had a \setmainfont already. This is for just one specific place

@user1935724 This is, why you should show a real minimal working example instead of a code snippet only. Currently this is IMHO a possible answer to the question.

Just use package raleway:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{raleway}

\begin{document}

\sffamily% Raleway is a sans-serif font.
Normal \textit{italic} \textbf{bold} \textit{\textbf{bold italic}}.

\end{document}

It works with PDFLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, and XeLaTeX and results in:

With LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX the package provides additional commands to select the Raleway in different weights:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{raleway}

\begin{document}

\raleway
Normal \textit{italic} \textbf{bold} \textit{\textbf{bold italic}}.

\ralewaymedium
Normal \textit{italic} \textbf{bold} \textit{\textbf{bold italic}}.

\ralewaylight
Normal \textit{italic} \textbf{bold} \textit{\textbf{bold italic}}.

\ralewayextra
Normal \textit{italic} \textbf{bold} \textit{\textbf{bold italic}}.

\ralewaythin
Normal \textit{italic} \textbf{bold} \textit{\textbf{bold italic}}.


\end{document}


See the package documentation for more information, e.g., about features and options provided by the package,e.g., option nosfdefault to not change the default sans-serif font.

Never use \fontspec in a document. It's inefficient and heavy.
As a general rule, you shouldn't mix fonts: having two different sans serif fonts in a document is generally not the best idea.
Anyway, the document is yours and you decide.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
%\setmainfont{MyBestSerifFont}[<options>]
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
%\setsansfont{MyBestSansFont}[<options>]

\newfontfamily{\raleway}{Raleway}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  UprightFont=*-Medium,
  ItalicFont=*-Medium-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-Bold-Italic,
]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textrlw}{\raleway}

\begin{document}

Normal font and \textsf{serif font}

\textrlw{Raleway upright} and \textit{\textrlw{Raleway italic}}

\end{document}


